# Can I merge these three lines of code into one line?

Tags: objective-c

I like to combine multiple lines of code into one, when I can.  Example:

```
int64_t siz    = [self getFileSizeAsInt64_t: filePath];
NSString * str = [self convLongLongToCommaStr: siz];
return( str );
```

becomes

```
return [self convLongLongToCommaStr: [self getFileSizeAsInt64_t: filePath]];
```

Here is an example of a three-line code pattern I see in my code a lot that I'd like to combine into one line.  But, I've not been able to do it and I'm not sure if it is even possible.

```
UIImageView * imgView = ctlObjs[iImgIdx];
[imgView setImage: nextImage];
ctlObjs[iImgIdx] = imgView;
```

Thanks for any insights on how to do this, if it is possible.

Comment: I don't think the last line is necessary of the three. It's already got a reference to that object.

Comment: Personally I get the feeling you are trying to make your code as hard to read as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

`[ctlObjs[iImgIdx] setImage:nextImage];`

Comment: To me, Aleksey's single line is a lot more palatable to read than the three lines I originally had.

Answer (score 2):

As Yar points out, that third line is not necessary. But you could combine the first two like so:

```
[ctlObjs[iImgIdx] setImage:nextImage];
```

Or, if `ctlObjs` is a `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, you might want the following, which makes the intent clear and offers better code completion:

```
[(UIImageView *) ctlObjs[iImgIdx] setImage:nextImage];
```

Having said that, the fact that you *can* combine multiple lines of code into one doesn't mean that you necessarily *should.* IMHO, code legibility is probably more important than compactness. I personally would stick with:

```
UIImageView *imgView = ctlObjs[iImgIdx];
[imgView setImage: nextImage];
```

Comment: I'll second the point about keeping the lines separate. It makes the code easier to read and easier to debug. You don't win points for using less lines of code.